# Unable to replace SVG tspan in IE/Edge

Tags: html, internet-explorer, svg, microsoft-edge

I have the following JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8dc9ww9a/

This is my SVG found in my HTML:

```
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="red">
  </circle>
  <text y=50>
    <tspan id="my-text" x=50 text-anchor="middle">Old Text</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

I have a Javascript function which when called, updates the text inside `<tspan>` to "New Text". This function works fine in all browsers except for IE/Edge.

Why does this happen and what can I do to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question answered mine: [Updating SVG text using jQuery in IE9-11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20100668/updating-svg-text-using-jquery-in-ie9-11)

`$('#my-text').prop('textContent','New Text');` when using JQuery is the correct way to do it.

Comment: I would have been better just to vote to close this as a duplicate wouldn't it?